# Transaction reverted

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have 3 users in Safe Alice, Bob, Charlie and need 2/3 signs. I added Bob as guard and now try to send 0.1 GOR from Safe to Bob. Alice sign this transaction, but Bob and Charley cant sign it now, because transaction is potentially fail. This is logs from tenderly. I think I miss something. https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/7531cb5a-08d6-4645-9fd6-5b9ec66747cd

```
Guard(guard).checkTransaction(
```

What I missed? How to correct send transaction with enabled Guard?